# How to fix errors with Firebase storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome, firebase-storage

I am trying to use Firebase storage to have people download files. I am not going to create a file upload, I am just going to upload files through Firebase console because I am the only person ever going to need to and I won't need to upload much. I have created a small static website from HTML and CSS. I deployed it to Firebase hosting and it works fine.

I uploaded a file to storage using the Firebase console and then read the documentation on creating a reference and downloading files from it. I added the necessary js libraries and then below it the config info for my project. I tried clicking the button but nothing happened. This error appears in the console:

[image]

Here is the code for the one page that uses Firebase:

```html
    <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <link rel="icon" type="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Railsplitters Patrol</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="topnav">
        <img src="/logo.png" alt="Railsplitters Logo" width="50px" height="50px">
        <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="/campouts.html">Campouts</a>
        <a href="/archive.html">Full Archive</a>
    </div>
    <h1>Railsplitters Patrol List 7/22/20</h1>
    <p>This is a list of everyone in the patrol and everyones patrol/troop position.</p>
    <script src="/__/firebase/7.16.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="/__/firebase/7.16.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
        <script src="/__/firebase/7.16.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <script>
    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyDpnXCe2mN3KSUaaQu03c1ItcPyN-SgXUQ",
        authDomain: "railsplitters-patrol.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://railsplitters-patrol.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "railsplitters-patrol",
        storageBucket: "railsplitters-patrol.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "733170749990",
        appId: "1:733170749990:web:cc4b43fc4f07cfebb34ce7",
        measurementId: "G-MRDVNH7BLH"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      var storage = firebase.storage();
      var storageRef = storage.ref();
      var fileRef = storageRef.child('files/patrollist72220.docx');
      function download() {
      fileRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.responseType = 'blob';
          xhr.onload = function(event) {
              var blog = xhr.response;
          };
          xhr.open('GET', url);
          img.src = url;
      }).catch(function(error) {
      });
    }
    </script>
    <button onclick="download()">Download the file</button>
</body>
</html>
```

What do I need to do to fix this? This is my first Firebase storage project. I have used Firebase authentication before and never gotten successful results but I have used firebase hosting and dynamic links before. I am very new to JavaScript.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of error messages, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. And when you post the error message, I recommend also searching for it as I'm pretty sure that has been covered a few times before.

Answer (score 1):

Like the console error says, you have to initialize Firebase, like this:

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

More info:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: I added that line of code below the config and libraries and above the rest of the js code. I then deployed it and pressed the button. Nothing happened. It did not initiate a download, I looked in the console and there were no errors at all. Please tell me what I need to do to fix this.

Comment: Edit your post with your full code again so I can see

Comment: None. I just get 3 Info messages about content being loaded and 2 warnings from Grammarly about some kind of default root logger. The URL is https://railsplitters-patrol.firebaseapp.com/. Open that and navigate to Full Archive > Patrol List 7/22/20 and press the button and look at the console.

Comment: The API request works, check out the Network tab. https://i.imgur.com/eXSh8RS.png

You just have to display it correctly on the page.